# How do I get unique Linq-to-Entities results when there is no primary key?

Tags: linq, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I have an entity model of an Oracle data source over which I have no control.  Using this model I query a particular view to see get all volume price breaks for a given product:

[image]

As you can see, this view has no primary key.  Here is the LINQ I am using:

```
 var db = GetOracleDataContext();
 var result = db.ITEMPRICEBREAKS_V.Where(p => p.STOCKNO == stockId).ToList();
```

This works to some degree, but instead of returning four distinct records with their own quantities and pricing, it returns four *identical* records, each with the pricing and quantities of the first record ($4800, 0, 2).

I have no control over this view.  Is there another way I can structure my LINQ query so that I can get the four distinct values?

Comment: EF does not support operations on tables/views without a primary key. If they have none, all rows will map to the same entity and you'll get the same object returned 4 times. I assume you can use some hacky way to generate a unique number per row which you could trick EF to accept as a PK, but that would probably require changing your model.

Comment: You should add fields to the primary key of the entity model until you've got a key you know is unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only the fields you care about and use Distinct().  For example:

```
var result = db.ITEMPRICEBREAKS_V
    .Where(p => p.STOCKNO == stockId)
    .Select(p => p.Price)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

However, I'd strongly recommend, along with the other commenters, that you get a primary key involved.